# Django - modelform doesn't save image

Tags: python, django, apache, django-forms

I use Ubuntu 14.10 and apache2 web server. In my Django project i have the model with additional information about user:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = u'User profile'

   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile/avatar', blank=True, null=True)
   name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
   surname = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
   phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return '%s' % self.user
```

Here is my form:

```
class ExtraProfileDataForm(ModelForm):
   name = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your name'))
   surname = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your surname'))
   phone = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your phone'))
   birthday = forms.DateField(label=(u'Birthday'))
   avatar = forms.ImageField(label=(u'Avatar'))

   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      fields = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'birthday', 'avatar')

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(ExtraProfileDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = False
```

And this is the view:

```
@login_required
def UserFullDataForm(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ExtraProfileDataForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         profile_user = request.user
         user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=profile_user)
         user_profile.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
         user_profile.surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
         user_profile.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
         user_profile.birthday = form.cleaned_data['birthday']
         user_profile.avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
         user_profile.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
      else:
         return render(request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', {'form':form})
   else:
         form = ExtraProfileDataForm()
         context = {'form':form}
         return render (request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', context)
```

When i fill the form all fields saved to the database except image field. Chown of `media/profile/avatar` folders is `www-data` and chmod is 775. Log files is empty. I have no any errors to understand why its happens. Can you help me understand why its happens or what i have to do to see the error. Thank you.
PS. this how looks like media of the project in apache config:

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/project/media/
    <Directory /var/www/project/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to pass `request.FILES` in `form = ExtraProfileDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

```
def UserFullDataForm(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ExtraProfileDataForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():

         user_form = form.save(commit=False)

         user_form.user = request.user
         user_form.save()

         return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
      else:
         return render(request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', {'form':form})
   else:
         form = ExtraProfileDataForm()
         context = {'form':form}
         return render (request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add `request.FILES` but still nothing happens.

Comment: @Zagorodniy Olexiy save form object after `form.is_valid()` and try

Comment: After i add `form.save` i have another error `null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, null, , null, rtyrtyr, , ).`

Comment: Thank you very much i did all that you recommend but it doesn't save the image

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue had nothing to do with my Python code, which correctly did not return any errors.

The issue was my `<form>` html did not have **enctype** set to support file post.

Example:

```
<form action="." method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly! You seem to be the only answerer who knows this. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have some code which is not required. Just remove that code as `form.save()` will save your form. Change your view like this.

```
def UserFullDataForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExtraProfileDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = ExtraProfileDataForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render (request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', context)
```

As you form is storing data in two different tables, you have to write your own save function for your form like this.

```
def save(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
    user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
    # get or create record for UserProfile against user and save it
```

In your `settings.py`, add following

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your project `urls.py`, add following line at the end

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You model will be changed like this

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/avatar', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I did what you recommend and after that i have  another error `null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, null, , null, rtyrtyr, , ).`

Comment: Thank you very much i did all that you recommend but it doesn't save the image

Comment: have you set  MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your settings.py. If yes then add `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in you project `urls.py`. Check this(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-root) documentation for MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: this is my MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL files `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`, i serve media and static files by apache server